# Cannot call function from another (included) file in PHP

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, localhost, include

I have a file that does this:

```
<?php
    //note: this is in 'testPage.php'
    include(NAVBAR_PATH); 
    registerSource(__FILE__);
?>
```

Where NAVBAR_PATH is a constant from a required file which is basically structured like 'https://localhost/path/to/navbar.php'.

in navbar.php, I have a part of code like so:

```
$SOURCE = 'none';
    function registerSource($sourcename){
        global $SOURCE;
        $SOURCE = $sourcename;
}
```

The function is supposed to be called and register the variable.
What happens, though, is that the source can't find the function and throws `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function registerSource() in C:\xampp\htdocs\iperguida\pages\testPage.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\iperguida\pages\testPage.php on line 17` instead.

I have tried using global variables or a define() but neither worked.
I have also checked here on StackOverflow for a similar case, and the only one there was had been fixed by referencing the other file by using an 'absolute URL' rather than a 'global URL'

I'm not sure what a 'global URL' is, but by looking up the definition of an absolute URL, it seems like I am already using that.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

The path - which, yes, is an URL, my apologies - is referring towards a file that is within the project folder. I decided not to use relative/global paths because I couldn't find a way to reference the base folder without having to go trough the whole path from htdocs. If I can't find a solution I'll just do that.

if you need the file structure of my project it's like this:

```
.
│   changelog.txt
│   const.php
│   index.php
│
├───content
│       navbar.php
│
└───pages
        testPage.php
```

Edit 2:

I had tried having stuff like `__DIR__` for global paths. Unfortunately it acted in a way I was unable to predict well. for instance - if I remember correctly - when instanced in const.php and read in navbar.php it would point to the `__DIR__` of navbar.php rather than const.php.

When I get the time I'll try to make a minimum reproducible example for this.

Comment: I do notice that the value of your `NAVBAR_PATH` starts with `https://` which is not a path, but an URL. See: [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). You can include an URL, but that is rare and you called it a PATH. However, there's not enough code/information in your question to reproduce your problem. What is in `testPage.php`? Etc. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Include files should be local available to the app. Running code from an external source is evil.

Comment: An easy way to use an absolute path is when you define a constant in `const.php` like this: `const WEB_ROOT = __DIR__;`. See: [Magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php). You can then use: `include(WEB_ROOT . "/content/navbar.php");` in your test page. There are other methods as well, my point is, absolute paths shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Read https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths to clear up your confusion about paths and how to specify them